# Trying to make a VR fps game in Unity, but my gun is randomly inaccurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, virtual-reality

Newbie to unity and vr here.

I recently got started with Valem's unity tutorial for VR, but I've hit a snag:

In his [part 5 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMu7hKUX3Oo) where he explains how to pick up and interact with objects, the code he uses for the gun results in the bullets being very inaccurate when I used it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.XR;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 40;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform barrel;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;

    public void Fire()
    {
        GameObject spawnedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
        spawnedBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);// = speed * barrel.forward;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
        Destroy(spawnedBullet, 2);
    }
}
```

In his video his gun fires accurately, but for me it randomly shoots in a different direction (usually forward but rarely straight).

Really need help, I've been hitting my head against this one all day.

Comment: Check the forward vector (z) of the transform that this script is on.  Does that object face the direction you expect it to?